# Flot Stacked Bar

Tags: jquery, charts, flot

[image: flot screenshot]

So I have the above flot stacked bar using flot.  Right now I also have a hover effect where when over any bar within that the main bar, it shows the number for that part.  What I want to show is the percentage for part that they are over in reference to the current bar instead of the number however I don't see anywhere how I can get to total of the bar (ie, looking for the number that is around 4200 based on this bar).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to get the total you will need to look at the data and find the elements in the series that correspond to the clicked item, then sum their values.

```
       <div id="placeholder" style="width:600px;height:300px;"></div>
    <div id="clickdata" ></div>


<script id="source">
$(function () {
    var d1 = [];
    for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i += 1)
        d1.push([i, parseInt(Math.random() * 30)]);

    var d2 = [];
    for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i += 1)
        d2.push([i, parseInt(Math.random() * 30)]);

    var d3 = [];
    for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i += 1)
        d3.push([i, parseInt(Math.random() * 30)]);

    var stack = 0, bars = true, lines = false, steps = false;

    function plotWithOptions() {
       return $.plot($("#placeholder"), [ d1, d2, d3 ], {
            grid: { clickable: true },
            series: {
                stack: stack,
                lines: { show: lines, fill: true, steps: steps },
                bars: { show: bars, barWidth: 0.6, hoverable: true, clickable: true }
            }
        });

    }

    var plot = plotWithOptions();

    function getTotalForIndex(index) {
        var total = parseFloat(d1[index][1]) + parseFloat(d2[index][1]) + parseFloat(d3[index][1]);
        return total;
    }

    $("#placeholder").bind("plotclick", function (event, pos, item) {
        if (item) {
            $("#clickdata").text("You clicked point " + item.dataIndex + " in " + item.series.label + ". which has total value "+ getTotalForIndex(item.dataIndex));
            plot.highlight(item.series, item.datapoint);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I am not looking for the total in the series, I am look for the total in the bar.  If series1 is [[1,2],[2,6]] and series2 is [[1,12],[2,52]]  I want to get the totals of bar1 - 14 and bar2 = 58 not series1 = 8 and series2 = 64.  I have looks at the item for the flothover event but I only see the series data, not the bar data.

Comment: If you run my example it gives the total in the bar not the series. The get total for index, finds the values in each series for the bar index and returns the total

Comment: Opps, didn't realize the code example was scrollable, looks like it should work.  Was hoping I would not have to do that, I would figure that the bar total would be something flot itself would provide.

Comment: @Richard what if i have dynamic series, how can i get bar total?